# Android Material UI dialog, keep the dialog open when the button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-ui, android-alertdialog

I want my dialog to stay open when I press the OK button, because I want to make the Alert Dialog the place to input the verification code. Is there a way to keep the Alert Dialog from closing?

```
                                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext())
                                        .setTitle("Verifikasi email")
                                        .setIcon(R.drawable.icons8_checkmark)
                                        .setMessage("message")
                                        .setView(viewDig)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                // Aksi yang akan dilakukan ketika tombol "OK" diklik
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                                for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
                                                    sb.append(editText.getText().toString());
                                                }
                                                String verNum = sb.toString();

                                                if (verNum.equals(activation)){
                                                    // do something without closing the dialog
                                                }else{
                                                    // do something without closing the dialog
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.show();
```

Comment: you've done dialog.dismiss inside onClick of the OK button , remove that line the dialog wont disappear

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvGnYnRnA4uWQEkmgSDDR-KT

Comment: it still disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm, the Alert dialog is working. I just need to make the PostiveButton null and make the onClick listener separate from the PositiveButton , here is the code

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext())
        .setTitle("Verifikasi email")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icons8_checkmark)
        .setMessage("message")
        .setView(viewDig)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setCancelable(false);

dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something when the "OK" button is clicked
                // Add your desired functionality here

                // To keep the dialog open, do not call dialog.dismiss()
            }
        });
    }
});

dialog.show();
```